# Unable to read from config file in console app in c#

Tags: c#, exception, visual-studio-2012, configuration, app-config

I am trying to read two variables from app.config file in my project in Visual Studio 2012. However I get an exception of : "Configuration System failed to initialize". Any ideas what is wrong here?

Here is my app.config file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <configurationSections>
    <section name ="connectionConfig" type="ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection"
             />
  </configurationSections>
  <connectionConfig  portNumber="7777"/>
  <connectionConfig  hostName="localhost" />
</configuration>
```

The C# file:

```
          namespace ConnectionManager
            {
                public class MyConnectionConfigurationSection : System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
                {
                    [ConfigurationProperty("portNumber")]
                    public string PortNumber
                    {
                        get
                        {
                            return (string)this["portNumber"];
                        }
                    set
                    {
                        this["portNumber"] = value;
                    }
                }

                [ConfigurationProperty("hostName")]
                public string HostName
                {
                    get
                    {
                        return (string)this["hostName"];
                    }
                    set
                    {
                        this["hostName"] = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public static class ConnectionApplication
            {
                public static MyConnectionConfigurationSection Config { get; internal set; }

                public static void Initialize()
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Config = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("connectionConfig") as MyConnectionConfigurationSection ;
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
                    }

                }

            }
    class Program
        {
            static string portNumber;
            static string hostName;
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ConnectionApplication.Initialize();

                portNumber=ConnectionApplication.Config.PortNumber;
                Console.WriteLine(portNumber);

                hostName = ConnectionApplication.Config.HostName;
                Console.WriteLine(hostName);

            }
        }
}
```

It seems that its not being able to initialize only...when i dump the exception, the exception says : Configuration System failed to initialize. Any suggestions what am i doing wrong

Comment: You have declared `PortNumber` property as `string` and in the `Program` class `portNubmer` is declared as `int`.

Comment: sorry that was a typo...corrected now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your code again:

```
  <configurationSections>
    <section name ="connectionConfig" type="ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection"
             />
  </configurationSections>
  <connectionConfig  portNumber="7777"/>
  <connectionConfig  hostName="localhost" />
```

- It's `<configSections>`
- Why do you declare twice your custom section? `<connectionConfig portNumber="7777" hostName="localhost" />` is the right way of using your custom section.
- `<section name ="connectionConfig" type="ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection" />` on `type` attribute should provide the full assembly qualified name of the class. That is, if your assembly is called `ConnectionManager` you should configure `ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection, ConnectionManager`.

BTW, in my opinion, if you're going to configure 2 simple settings, I wouldn't use a custom configuration section (this is an overkill). Why don't you just use `appSettings` which is built-in on .NET configuration model?

```
<appSettings>
     <add key="connectionManager:host" value="localhost" />
     <add key="connectionManager:port" value="7777" />
</appSettings>
```

And you'll access these parameters this way:

```
string host ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionManager:host"];
int port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionManager:port"]);
```

Comment: actually i was trying to learn the custom configurations therefore was just playing around...thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @Why I'm glad this solved your issues. I've been using custom configuration sections since .NET early days and it's a very powerful approach, because you get a typed configuration model and you don't need to waste your time with your own configuration validation engine...

Comment: +1 for offering an answer which solves the OP Issue :)

Answer (score 2):

Check your Configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <configurationSections>
        <section name ="connectionConfig" type="ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection"/>
    </configurationSections>
    <connectionConfig  portNumber="7777"/>
    <connectionConfig  hostName="localhost" />
</configuration>
```

The part containing the portnumber and hostname is outside the section your reading in your code.

Try it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <configurationSections>
        <section name ="connectionConfig" type="ConnectionManager.MyConnectionConfigurationSection">        
          <connectionConfig  portNumber="7777"/>
          <connectionConfig  hostName="localhost" />
        </section>
    </configurationSections>
</configuration>
```

Comment: No, i provided an Idea where the problem could be.

Comment: I believe your code wouldn't work. Maybe I'm completely wrong, but this isn't the .NET configuration schema

Comment: Maybe I got in my own mistake, but I believe your answer is erronous and I'm getting a hard time when I try to understand why you're getting positive votes. This isn't the standard .NET configuration model, which is the one for which OP asked for.

Comment: You may be right but its not allways about compilable code, an idea is an option to help people as well isnt it, and as i mentioned im not sure it would solve the issue but its just an idea.

Comment: Don't understand me wrong, any answer might be helpful, even if it doesn't solve the problem. My concern is you don't get an idea, because .NET configuration model isn't an opinion-based issue. It follows an XML schema and it gets deserialized into an object model. I mean, your answer creates confusion because this isn't a custom XML configuration. Your code would throw the same exception as OP's code!! :D